# Error using a lambda function for sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort a `std::vector` (containing indexes of another `std::vector`).

```
sort(inds.begin(), inds.end(), [&](int i1, int i2) { return compares[i1] < compares[i2]; } );
```

But it keeps getting me the following error:

[image]

I fixed it myself adding -std=c++11 to g++ command.

Comment: The first warning tells you why. Lambdas require C++11 but you are not compiling in C++11 mode.

Comment: It is clear from the first error message that you are not compiling your code in C++11 mode.  lambdas were introduced in C++11

Comment: I code Java and Python and do not understand the difference between different c++ modes and how to switch. I saw the warning. I googled it and did not find anything. I am pretty new in C++. I updated my g++, but the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error message carefully, especially the first line.

Then compare the versions of your toolchain on the two computers and check whether that might cause the difference in the default C dialact being assumed or whether you have different default flags for building in your environment variables or build environment or similar.